# Converting Pandas DataFrame to a Sankey like Structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a problem where the structure of data is like this

```
ID | Date | Category
---------------------
1  | 2 Feb| A
1  | 3 Feb| B
1  | 3 Feb| A
1  | 4 Feb| C
2  | 3 Feb| A 
5  | 2 Feb| B
5  | 4 Feb| A
```

I want to make a combination of every three of them in order of date as per the ID with frequency.

So I am looking for putting the above table in this format

```
ID | Cat 1 | Cat 2 | Cat 3 | Freq
---------------------------------
1  | A     | B     | A     | 1
1  | B     | A     | C     | 1
2  | A     |       |       | 1
5  | B     | A     |       | 1
```

I have tried using pivot table and reshaping data but to no avail.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `shift` method after grouping by ID to get this format.

The code would look something like this:

```
df['Cat 1'] = df['Category']
df['Cat 2'] = df.groupby('ID')['Category'].shift(-1)
df['Cat 3'] = df.groupby('ID')['Category'].shift(-2)
df.groupby(['ID','Cat 1','Cat 2','Cat 3']).agg(
   Freq=pd.NamedAgg('some_variable','count')
)
```